# strongloop loopback send email

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, strongloop

I see that loopback comes with nodemailer integrated as a node module.
I tried to follow the docs to send a hello world mail via the angular-sdk

http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#emailsendoptions-callback

However, the docs are not really specific here. I tried the following:

```
    User.email
      from: "info@test.com"
      to: "sven@gmail.com"
      subject: "hello world"
      html: "<b> Hello Wolrd </b>"
```

which gives me this error, even though I have an authenticated user instance.

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/users/Emails 401 (Unauthorized) angular.js:8407

intercepted rejection of  /api/users/Emails 401
```

My question is how can I configure the email module as to set up SMTP etc.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks Sven

Comment: hey do you find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

This thread is quite old, but this is how you implement the loopback email feature:

```
MyModel.app.models.Email.send({
        to: To,
        from: From,
        subject: Subject,
        text: Text,
        html: Html
      }, function(err, mail) {
        console.log('Email Sent!');
        console.log(mail);
        cb(err);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we have any docs specifically on using Mail with the Angular SDK, but see http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Using+built-in+models#Usingbuilt-inmodels-Emailmodel for info on just sending an email message in LoopBack.  A good approach might be to get it working on the backend first and then try doing it via Angular.

Rand